# Tanslucent Java Chat showing duplicate components?

Tags: java, chat, transparent

Pretty much, once I make my JTextArea and my JTextField transparent, as I type it looks as if all of my components are being duplicated and added to the screen. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a NetBeans bug?

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
*
* @author xDaegothx
*/

public class Game extends JFrame
{
    JLayeredPane LP;
    Game_Chat GC;

    public Game()
    {
        LP = new JLayeredPane();
        LP.setBackground(Color.black);
        LP.setOpaque(true);

        GC = new Game_Chat();
        GC.setBounds(0,350,400,250);

        LP.add(GC);

        this.getContentPane().add(LP);
        this.setBounds(0,0,1200,700);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Game();
    }

public class Game_Chat extends JLabel
{
    JTextArea TA;
    JScrollPane JSP;
    JTextField TF;
    JButton Submit_btn;

    public Game_Chat()
    {
        TA = new JTextArea();
        TA.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255,0));
        TA.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,0));
        TA.setOpaque(true);
        TA.setText("Welcome to 'Game'!");

        JSP = new JScrollPane(TA);
        JSP.setOpaque(true);
        JSP.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255,0));
        JSP.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,0));
        JSP.setBounds(0,0,400,225);

        TF = new JTextField();
        TF.setOpaque(true);
        //TF.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,0));
        TF.setBounds(0,225,350,25);

        Submit_btn = new JButton("Send");
        Submit_btn.setBorder(null);
        Submit_btn.setBounds(350,225,50,25);

        TF.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                Submit();
            }
        });

        Submit_btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
            {
                Submit();
            }
        });

        add(JSP);
        add(TF);
        add(Submit_btn);

        setBackground(Color.gray);
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    public void Submit()
    {
        String charname = "MyName";
        TA.append("\n"+charname+": "+TF.getText());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Java convention states that you should use a lowercase letter to start non final variable names.

Comment: i don't understand your question.. i run your code and i don't understand what is your issue.. Some advices 1) Follow java code conventions as commented above 2) don't use `setBounds` instead rely in LayoutManager cause your software have to run in diferent resolutions

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of setting both the foreground and background transparent? You will never see the text if it is transparent!

Anyway to make a component completely transparent you don't play with the background. Instead you just use:

```
textArea.setOpaque(false);
```

If you want partially transparent backgrounds then you do use the setBackground() method. But you will have painting problems. See [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for an explanation of the problems and some potential solutions.

Also, you should NOT be using setBounds() to set the size/location of a component. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. So take the time to learn how to use them for better functioning programs.